# Help with Shift/Reduce conflict - Trying to model (X A)* (X B)*

Tags: parsing, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict, gppg

Im trying to model the EBNF expression

```
("declare" "namespace" ";")* ("declare" "variable" ";")*
```

I have built up the yacc (Im using MPPG) grammar, which seems to represent this, but it fails to match my test expression.

The test case i'm trying to match is

```
declare variable;
```

The Token stream from the lexer is

```
KW_Declare
KW_Variable
Separator
```

The grammar parse says there is a "Shift/Reduce conflict, state 6 on KW_Declare". I have attempted to solve this with "%left PrologHeaderList PrologBodyList", but neither solution works.

```
Program                     : Prolog;
Prolog                      : PrologHeaderList PrologBodyList;

PrologHeaderList            : /*EMPTY*/
                            | PrologHeaderList PrologHeader;
PrologHeader                : KW_Declare KW_Namespace Separator;

PrologBodyList              : /*EMPTY*/
                            | PrologBodyList PrologBody;
PrologBody                  : KW_Declare KW_Variable Separator;
```

KW_Declare KW_Namespace KW_Variable Separator are all tokens with values "declare", "naemsapce", "variable", ";".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've used anything yacc-like, but here are a couple of suggestions that may or may not help.

It seems that you need a 2-token lookahead in this situation. The parser gets to the last *PrologHeader*, and it has to decide whether the next construct is a *PrologHeader* or a *PrologBody*, and it can't tell that from the KW_Declare. If there's a directive to increase lookahead in this situation, it will probably solve the problem.

You could also introduce context into your actions: rather than define *PrologHeaderList* and *PrologBodyList*, define *PrologRuleList* and have the actions throw an error if a header appears after a body. Ugly, but sometimes you have to do it: what appears simple in a grammar may not be simple in the generated parser.

A hackish approach might be to combine the tokens: rather than *KW_Declare* and *KW_Variable*, have your lexer recognize the space and use *KW_Declare_Variable*. Since both are keywords, you're not going to run into namespace collision problems.

Comment: This is the approach I adopted in the end. I figure I can do the validation in code.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar at the top is regular so IIRC you can plot it out as a DFA (or a NDA and convert it to a DFA) and then convert the DFA to a grammar. It's bean a while so I'll leave the work as an exercise for the reader.